# see something done/ see something being done

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs-of-perception

As far as I know, we use "see something do" if we see an action from the beginning to the end. And we use "see something doing" if we see an action in progress. I wonder about passive form of this usage. Am I allowed to use "see something done" if we see that action from the beginning to the end?

> 1- She ***saw her dragon shot out*** of the sky.
>
> 2- She ***saw her friend killed***.

I have seen this sentences above in a tv-series(Game of Thrones) . Are this examples above right? or should we use this versions below?

> 1a- She ***saw her dragon being shot*** out of the sky.
>
> 2a- She ***saw her friend being killed***.

Comment: "She saw her dragon shoot out of the sky" and (2a) is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both examples are grammatically correct.

However, you would use 1) and 2) when the action is complete, or is instant (and therefore complete by default.) For example, you would only say "I saw my friend being shot" if the friend got shot over a period of time (multiple shots were fired and hit the friend)

You would use 1a) and 2a) when her seeing of the action is interrupted. She would have only seen her friend killed if they finished killing them (since this is a process.) Whether this interruption actually interrupts her seeing the event doesn't matter; all that matters is that something else happens during the process of killing or shooting or whatever is happening to her friend.